# SSRS - Report item not linked to a DataSet

Tags: reporting-services

I an having an issue in SSRS.
I am using SSDT 2015.

Step 1:
I am using reporting services project.
Created a Report
Added a Data Source
Added a Data Set

[image: My SSRS Report Image]

Step 2:
I'm adding a parameter/Expression, but if I go to available value and try to add a data set field it is showing me: **"Report item not linked to a dataset."**

[image: Error image]

I was working with SSRS previously for 20 days and it didn't happen.

Comment: I hope you want to see the parameters in expressions window

Comment: @SanthakumarMunuswamy : I am creating an Expression in Available Value property of Parameters there i can not see the Fields of the Dataset
Is the flow of parameters are like this only??

Comment: I have a working parameter in a report and it also says the same message. 'Report item not linked to report'. What parameter are you trying to include?

Comment: i also see the same, if you want to use a field from your dataset query, choose option 'Get values from a query'. Specify values option won't give you dataset fields in values. This option is to specify values in report parameters which will be passed to the dataset queries (its seems you are trying to use the dataset result field to pass as parameter to same dataset query) .

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still experiencing this problem, if you click on the rectangle (the white background, not any of the elements on top of this), and you should see the grey borders appear. If you then right-click on the top-left of the grey borders, and select 'Tablix Properties', you can then link your tablix to your dataset, by changing the 'Dataset name' drop down to the name of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set the parameter to get values from a query, or you can use an aggregate function (e.g. `first()`) to get the first value from a dataset that the item is not linked to. That would be:
 `=first(Fields!ActorID.Value, "dtsActor")`

Also, yay WiseOwl.